# Maintain a mysql connections between calls to php files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How can I have a mysql connection maintained between calls to external .php files? I lose like, almost 2 seconds everytime to reconnect to the database, which is way too much. Btw, I heard persistent connections are bad, so I'm looking for an alternative, unless you convince me they are ok.

In home.php I have:

```
function GetCardSuggestionList(firstChars) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'GetCardList.php',
        datatype: 'text',
        data: ({FirstChars: firstChars}),
        success: function(suggestionList) {
            ShowSuggestionList(eval(suggestionList));
        }
    });
}
```

and in GetCardList.php, I have:

```
<?php

$cardFirstChars = $_POST['FirstChars'];
$foundCardList = array();

$dbCon=mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");
$queryResult = mysqli_query($dbCon, "SELECT name FROM card WHERE name LIKE '%" . $cardFirstChars . "%'");

while($suggList = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult)) {
    array_push($foundCardList, $suggList['name']);
}

echo json_encode( $foundCardList );

?>
```

**Update:** *While the answer I chose as best does not actually answer the question, it got me rid of my underlying problem, which was a speed issue.*

Comment: Persistent connections __are__ your alternative; but if it's taking 2 seconds to connect to the database each time, there's something seriously wrong: is it on localhost, or on a remote server?

Comment: What could it be? IT looks like it is precisely this line taking long: $dbCon=mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");

Comment: How do you know that it looks like that line? Have you profiled your code to see if that really is the case? Are you sure that your problem isn't the query, which can't use any indexing because of the LIKE, but is using a full table search

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't know how to profile, but I do believe it is the case since moving that line anywhere else in the code will result in the 2 seconds delay to happen where that line should be executing.

Comment: If you're searching `name` for names __beginning with__ $cardFirstChars, then use `LIKE '" . $cardFirstChars . "%'");`

Comment: Moving that line in the code will give you major problems in that short piece of code

Comment: @MarkBaker Of course my code is longer. If I put the connection right at the beginning of my main page, the whole page won't load before like, a +/- 2 seconds delay. And I forgot to change the var name to something like "cardChars" rather than cardFirstChars.

Comment: Your code is still doing a full table scan, which is more likely to be a performance overhead than actually connecting to the database

Comment: But the easiest way to profile is to record the start and end times for a block of code, and then subtract one from the other to work out how many (milli)seconds that line takes to execute

Comment: @MarkBaker Simply moving the "$dbCon=mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");" line, without doing the search, will take about 2 seconds, even if I don't search the table.

Comment: OK! you clearly know best.... moving the line to __where__; and why do you think simply moving the line somewhere else in your code makes it execute faster or more slowly

Comment: @MarkBaker I am not saying it makes it run faster or slower. I am saying moving the said line somewhere else in the code will make the code take 2 seconds before moving on at the time it is supposed to be executing that line.

Comment: Please explain how you're measuring which line in the code takes so long if you're not profiling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ip address like `127.0.0.1` for localhost or servers ip address instead of localhost or hostname. For me this speeded up my db connection to blink of an eye from few seconds.

This seems to be a problem especially **on Windows**

Comment: My god! Many thanks! I'm not wondering whether or not I still need to maintain the connection!

Comment: If this worked, please mark as an answer so others with same problem find the solution.

Comment: Are you aware of any way to maintain a connection anyway so I can gain more speed, or is it actually useless or bad in some way? It is worth mentioning that as you wrote, the speed does pass from a few seconds, to the blink of an eye.

Comment: I found this, maybe it has the information you need. I myself don't know any website that uses persistent connection, but maybe if your db load is huge you could try it. Also if your are on unix/linux you can connect to mysql socket instead of server with tcp/ip and it would speed things up just a little bit more. Unix socket works with PDO, I don't know about other mysql client libraries . Here's the link for persisten connections http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: Maintaining a connection is what "persistent connections" are. If bypassing the resolver solved most of your speed issue, you may want to think hard if the minimal speed gain from using them is worth the gotchas you'll have to deal with.

Comment: Thanks. I have read that persistent connections are deprecated though. But I just realized I forgot to change the "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" somewhere else, and now speed is far from an issue. A thousand thanks... I havve been searching a solution for like, 3 hours or more.

Comment: If this helps you, your DNS is busted. DNS should always answer in a few ms unless you have some well known reason why you don't have access to a normal level of service (like you're on satellite or dial up). Tell your ISP or site admins that there's a strange 2 second delay on resolving that hostname.